# Jquery get textarea value on pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get value of a text area on pressing enter but getting value undefined.

```
jQuery(".comment-form .comments-text").on('keypress', function (e) {
    if(e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var text = jQuery(this).value;
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

on keypress is working fine but cannot get the text I am entering.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:
HTML

```html
<form class="comment-form">
  <textarea class="comments-text"></textarea>
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$(".comment-form .comments-text").on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var text = e.target.value;
    console.log('text', text);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please check it as answered so I get some points :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can get value of **textArea** with `val();` method in `jquery`

```
let value = $("textArea").val();
alert(value);
```